# Filter distribution of Latent variable models

Tags: reference-request, papers, definitions, probability-distribution

In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00953.pdf, about stochastic latent variable models, the paper says "We use the
reparameterization trick to sample from the filtering distribution". I read the paper, and looked up what it was. I'm a self-learning reading the paper. Can anyone tell me or give me a reference on what a filtering distribution is?